# Dictionary Content copy from one model to another model

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have a following dictionaries.

```
firstDict=Dictionary<string,X>

SecondDict=Dictionary<string,y>
```

where X and Y indicate the model class and x and y contains the same properties ,but x and y are in different name spaces.

How can I copy `firstDict` contents to `secondDict` ?

Is there any direct way?

Comment: This depends. Is X implicitly or explicitly convertible into Y? (i.e. would `(Y)xObj` work?) If yes, then you can copy the arrays

Comment: X and Y classes contains the same properties. I mean Y class is the exact copy of X class.

Comment: But if they are not related to each other, i.e. derived so that the compiler can use a class hierarchy, this only can work if they are dynamics

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the properties manually (or use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)):

```
var firstDict = new Dictionary<string, FirstNameSpace.X>();
var secondDict = new Dictionary<string, SecondNameSpace.Y>();

foreach (var pair in firstDict) {
    var y = new SecondNameSpace.Y();
    y.Prop1 = pair.Value.Prop1;
    // ... '
    secondDict.Add(pair.Key, y);
}
```

Another option that doesn't make it simpler but safer is to provide a copy-constructor or factory-method in `Y` that takes a `X` instance and encapsulates this.

Comment: This is not C#, although your answer is correct. If the classes are related to each other or if they are dynamics, you don't need to do this.

Comment: @Psi: thought it was VB.NET (maybe because of the pseudo code). Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I've done the below.. it seems to work. MyClassOne is in my UI and the MyClassTwo is in a seperate assembly called business which is imported.

```
using Business;

    var firstDict = new Dictionary<string,MyClassOne>
    {
        {"Key1", new MyClassOne() {PropertyOne = "FirstValue1"}}
    };

    var secondDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClassTwo>
    {
        {"Key2", new MyClassTwo() {PropertyOne = "SecondValue1"}}
    };

    foreach (var entryToCopy in firstDict)
    {
        secondDict.Add("NewStringKey", new MyClassTwo(){PropertyOne = entryToCopy.Value.PropertyOne});
    }
```

Hope that's what you're after..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` to do this

```
Dictionary<string, Y> secondDict = firstDict.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => new Y {prop1 = pair.Value.prop1, prop2 = pair.Value.prop2, ...});
```